# Flutter project is not building web app , but it could be build two weeks ago

Tags: flutter

I am working on a production project, and no suddenly I am not able to build the web app, which I could build only two weeks ago.

Here you have the complete error output:

```
modestovascofornas@MacBook-Air-de-modesto capenergy_ns % flutter build web

 Building with sound null safety 

Target dart2js failed: Exception: Warning: The 'dart2js' entrypoint script is deprecated, please use 'dart compile js' instead.
Error: Error when reading
'file:///Volumes/ModesSSD#1/Proyectos%20en%20curso/Capenergy/2022_G3_CAPENERGY_NS/capenergy_ns/.dart_tool/flutter_build/d53138d5fdb7d0ae38b7d7e14
72afba3/main.dart': Unsupported operation: Cannot extract a file path from a URI with a fragment component
Error: No 'main' method found.
Error: Compilation failed.


#0      Dart2JSTarget.build (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/targets/web.dart:225:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      _BuildInstance._invokeInternal (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/build_system.dart:847:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      Future.wait.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:522:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      _BuildInstance.invokeTarget (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/build_system.dart:785:32)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      Future.wait.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:522:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      _BuildInstance.invokeTarget (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/build_system.dart:785:32)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      FlutterBuildSystem.build (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/build_system.dart:614:16)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      buildWeb (package:flutter_tools/src/web/compile.dart:53:32)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      BuildWebCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/build_web.dart:135:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1257:27)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#11     CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#12     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:283:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#13     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#14     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:229:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#15     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:64:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#16     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#17     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:91:3)
<asynchronous suspension>

Compiling lib/main.dart for the Web...                             216ms
Exception: Failed to compile application for the Web.
```

What can I do to solve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the error message you provided, it appears that there are two issues that are preventing the web app from being built successfully:

1. The `dart2js` entrypoint script is deprecated, and you should use `dart compile js` instead.
2. No 'main' method found.

To resolve the first issue, You need to update/Modify  your build command

```
flutter build web --web-renderer html --release --no-sound-null-safety && \
dart compile js -o web/main.dart.js web/main.dart
```

Hope this works!